# SQL Server - Convert a SELECT statement into a DELETE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The below select statement selects ALL records that have duplicates (including the original).

How do I convert the below SELECT statement to a DELETE or DELETE-WHERE statement?

```
select *
  from Csv a
  join ( select EmployeeId, DivisionId 
          from Csv 
          group by EmployeeId, DivisionId 
          having count(*) > 1 ) b
    on a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
   and a.DivisionId = b.DivisionId;
```

The language is SQL Server/MS-SQL

Note: There is no ID column.

Comment: When you say 'convert to a delete statement' do you mean 'a delete query that will delete the rows this selects?'

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: This will delete ALL instances of a  (EmployeeId, DivisionId) double . Are you sure?

Comment: @Serg - Correct. I want to delete all records that have duplicates, even the original.

Comment: @JonasMetzler - there is no Id column.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting all the doubles based on the original select

```
delete a
  from Csv a
  join ( select EmployeeId, DivisionId 
          from Csv 
          group by EmployeeId, DivisionId 
          having count(*) > 1 ) b
    on a.EmployeeId = b.EmployeeId
   and a.DivisionId = b.DivisionId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `COUNT(*)` window function in an updatable `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId, DivisionId) counter 
  FROM csv
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE counter > 1;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f64fc5e0123284981075bf5b48a7cc4).